# Push notifications with big Images using cordova push plugin

Tags: android, push-notification, cordova-plugins

I want to get push notification something like flipkart or myntra does. (Push notification will come with an Big image detailing about offers, on clicking of which will take to offers zone). Does anyone know how to get it done.
I have code something like this:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
        new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setDefaults(defaults)
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText("This is a test for push notification with big images."))
            .setLargeIcon(icon)
            .setSmallIcon(context.getApplicationInfo().icon)
            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
            .setContentTitle(extras.getString("title"))
            .setTicker(extras.getString("title"))
            .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
            .setAutoCancel(true);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometime back, I created a [pull request](https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin/pull/498) for this.

The significant code:

```
public void createBigPicNotification(Context context, Bundle extras)
{
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    String appName = getAppName(this);

    .
    .
    .


    String bigPictureUrl= null;
    bigPictureUrl=extras.getString("bigPicture");
    Bitmap bigPictureBMP = null;
    if (bigPictureUrl != null) {
        try {
        URL url = new URL(bigPictureUrl);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.connect();
        InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
            bigPictureBMP = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
        } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle bigPicStyle = new
        NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle();
    bigPicStyle.setBigContentTitle(extras.getString("title"));
    bigPicStyle.setSummaryText(extras.getString("message"));
    bigPicStyle.bigPicture(bigPictureBMP);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
        new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setDefaults(defaults)
            .setSmallIcon(context.getApplicationInfo().icon)
            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
            .setTicker(extras.getString("title"))
                    .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setStyle(bigPicStyle);

    String message = extras.getString("message");
    if (message != null) {
        mBuilder.setContentText(message);
    } else {
        mBuilder.setContentText("<missing message content>");
    }

    String msgcnt = extras.getString("msgcnt");
    if (msgcnt != null) {
        mBuilder.setNumber(Integer.parseInt(msgcnt));
    }

    int notId = 0;

    try {
        notId = Integer.parseInt(extras.getString("notId"));
    }
    catch(NumberFormatException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Number format exception - Error parsing Notification ID: " + e.getMessage());
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Number format exception - Error parsing Notification ID" + e.getMessage());
    }

    mNotificationManager.notify((String) appName, notId, mBuilder.build());
}
```