# Cordova local notifications plugin

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, localnotification

I would like to send an notification with an image within. But in the object properties there is no way to add an image.

Here is the plugin: https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications/wiki/05.-Update

Iam wondering if I can modify the notification object to send an image in the local notifications.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28718872/push-notifications-with-big-images-using-cordova-push-plugin Please visit it

Comment: Not related to this question. I am using local notifications.

Comment: using icon option you easily can set the image in notification.

Comment: I know that, my question is to push an image as notification instead of text.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your image to base64 encoded image and then add the encoded image to the notification object.

Here is an example:

```
var notificationObj = {
   title: "My title goes here",
   description: "My description goes here",
   img:"image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABg....AElFTkSuQmCC" //this is the base64 encoded image
}

//Schedule the notification code goes here
```

Then you would be able to access that base64 encoded image when the notification fires

```
cordova.plugins.notification.local.on("click", function (notification) {
    //The property notification.data.img now contains the base64 encoded image and
    // you can use it directly as a source for <img> tag. Example:

   document.getElementById("myImage").src= notification.data.img ;
});
```

Comment: How would you do that? I used this online converter: https://www.base64-image.de/

But I dont know what to include in the messgae of the notification? The html or what?

Comment: I tried it with this output: http://www.dailycoding.com/Utils/Converter/ImageToBase64.aspx. But it only shows me the output as a string

Comment: That's the point, you convert the image into base64 encoded string so that you can store it in the notification object.
Then when the user clicks the notification, it's retrieved in the notification object as string and you can then use it as you like.